# Find duplicates between 2 datatables and remove them

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have data from 2 different sql databases
I have created 2 datatables with the data
The columns are not the same in both datatables
But i need to find duplicates in the first column in both and remove them from the first datatable

This is the creation of the datatables

`                    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

```
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(comm1))
                {
                    adapter1.Fill(dt2);

                    DataTable[] dt3 = dt2.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select((row, index) => new { row, index })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 9999)  // integer division, the fractional part is truncated
                    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.row).CopyToDataTable())
                    .ToArray();`
```

`                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

```
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
                    {
                            adapter.Fill(dt);


                            string antal = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
                        File.AppendAllLines("E:\\Logs\\WashingMachine\\" + date + ".txt", new[] { "Rows in DB at " + ort + " =  " + antal + "  " });

                            DataTable[] dt1 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select((row, index) => new { row, index })
                            .GroupBy(x => x.index / 9999)  // integer division, the fractional part is truncated
                            .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.row).CopyToDataTable())
                            .ToArray();`
```

I have tried with this command:

`
public static DataTable CompareTwoDataTable(DataTable dt, DataTable dt2)
{
dt.Merge(dt2);
DataTable d3 = dt2.GetChanges();

```
        return d3;
    }
```

DataTable d5 = CompareTwoDataTable(dt, dt2);`

and

`var dtData3 = dt.AsEnumerable().Except(dt2.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);`

To get the duplicates but cant get it to work

Please help me

Comment: First, what is the CompareTwoDataTable? Second, you don't need to fill data table to delete from first table or get any data .AsEnumerable(). Just use delete command with relations to other table or query that searches duplicates.

Comment: I have updated the code with comparetwodatatable now

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you would like to identify a duplicate, if matching the whole item you can use LINQ and compare column and filter out the depreciate, otherwise create a customer comparison extension method to check if proprieties match.

matching all columns, something like below should work.

```
public static DataTable RemoveDuplicates(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
```

{
HashSet dt2FirstColumnData = new HashSet(dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row[0].ToString()));

```
DataTable result = dt1.Clone(); 
foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
    if (!dt2FirstColumnData.Contains(row[0].ToString()))
    {
        result.ImportRow(row);
    }
}

return result;
```

}

Comment: Can't get hashSet do work, my page is ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)

Answer (score -1):

For looking for duplicated you have to use Intersect.

You can select all the values of the column desired of each datatable and then apply the intersect.